# JavaFx How to add 4000 items in ChoiceBox

Tags: javafx, heap-memory

Is there any posibilty to add 4000 itmes in ChoiceBox. 
My code is working fine, but I get error Out of memory.

My code is:

```
 listItemsDevices.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(resultSet));
 listItemsDevices.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
 @Override
 public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
 indexOfSumarnoTehtniceDropdown =listItemsDevices.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
 System.out.println("INDEX "+indexOfSumarnoTehtniceDropdown);
 }  
 });
```

My FXML is:

```
 <ChoiceBox fx:id="listItemsDevices">
    <items>
       <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
         <String fx:value="Item 1" />
         <String fx:value="Item 2" />
         <String fx:value="Item 3" />
       </FXCollections>
    </items>
 </ChoiceBox>
```

I get error the most important is Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space. Any idea how to solve this problem??

```
     Exception in Application start method java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.jar.Manifest.read(Unknown Source)
at java.util.jar.Manifest.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference(Unknown Source)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$2.getManifest(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.updateCursorFrame(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit$9.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Application launch error
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.jar.Manifest$FastInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.util.jar.Manifest$FastInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.util.jar.Manifest.read(Unknown Source)
at java.util.jar.Manifest.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference(Unknown Source)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$2.getManifest(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.tkExit(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(Unknown Source)
... 2 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you can try to increase the heap size :)

But my recommendation is to use a lazy displaying strategy like android does it with list views. Only load these items, that are visible. That means, create  a ScrollPane with a fixed number of CheckBoxes (or less if you have less items). Listening for the scroll event. Load the items of the collection and connect there with the CheckBoxes. Typically you can improve the user experience by loading a fixed number of items before and after the current sub list to enbale faster scrolling.

Comment: How to increase heap size or is this a joke?? :D

Comment: @RobertP, you can specify the start and maximum heap size. Please take a look at the parameters -Xms and -Xmx: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html